# Do duplicate questions count towards a ban?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, post-ban

Six months ago I earned myself a question ban. I asked a bunch of sub-par questions and I deleted them when they hadn't been answered in a few days, not knowing that deleting questions would add towards my ban. I found the other day that the ban was lifted, so I asked a question and this question was quickly marked as a duplicate. It was a perfectly fair judgement, as the original question answered my inquiry, I just hadn't found it. However, I've found that my ban has been reinstated.

Has my ban come back because I asked a duplicate question?

Comment: Probably yes, closed questions (which includes duplicates) count in the ban algorithm.

Comment: Well then it seems I've gotten myself into a bit of a pickle.

Comment: They do count. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236947/159251

Comment: @JoshCaswell Your answer on that post definitely feels relevant right now. It seems duplicates can be appreciated by the community if they are upvoted, but the system considers them all negative. Hopefully something can be done about this by the time my ban wears off again.

Comment: I agree it’s unfair in this specific case (as this is not a trivially Googled duplicate and, on its face, not a bad question at all), but generally, a user asking a duplicate question after getting out of a q-ban is probably a *very* strong sign of a recidivist :( Anyway, you clearly aren’t the typical low-quality asker, perhaps the voting done by Meta users reading this question will get you back on track already and lift the ban.

Comment: I'm sorry you tripped over the question ban again, this time from a dupe. That said, @Pekka I would disagree that this was "not a bad question at all". The question fails to include an MCVE, and shows no evidence of any attempt to reduce the problem to anything even approximating a minimal example. It may be difficult to search for the exact same thing, but that's only because new programmers not familiar with the concept of pointers to objects always ask this question in very specific terms, even though they have the same broad problem as every other person who's asked the question.

Comment: Please in the future, take more care with your questions. Spend the time to investigate the problem yourself, which always includes getting the to the point where you can include a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Consider that when searching for similar or identical questions, the specific scenario you're dealing with may not be as important as the general behavior. You can also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for additional advice. The articles linked at the bottom are at least as important to read as the article itself.

Comment: Frankly, the upvotes you received for that question are much more an indication of differing philosophies on Stack Overflow regarding quality content, and especially of poor community evaluation of content. This is a constant problem: poor questions getting up-voted, while good questions are neglected. A few votes one way or the other are all most posts ever get, and unfortunately the number of votes is too small for the score to be indicative of anything in any significant way.

Comment: Question ban allows you to ask one question every 6 months.  If the question that you ask is not good enough then it wont lift you out of the ban.  The "one question every six months" feature has been discussed before on meta.  So your ban was not "reinstated", instead you were given one chance to see if you have improved.  You had not.

Comment: This seems unfortunate. Well done for attempting to correct your mistakes and making an effort.

Comment: @JK I did not know that it was only a one chance situation. It is recommended that prior questions be fixed as a way to increase odds of ending the ban early, and I'm left with no questions to fix, so I'm unsure how I am meant to get better at asking questions - which, I will admit, I'm not great at wrt Stack Overflow.

Comment: I often feel marking older questions as duplicate of new questions is problematic and not ethical because it may cause question ban for OP of older question, instead of the new one, and I think the vote of answers shows which answer is better already, using duplicate as extra indicator for better answer is obsolete at all

Comment: @amuse I am not *much* troubled by someone at the edge of a question ban being banned.  It takes more than one bad question to get a question ban.  Sure, it isn't perfectly predictable and fair, but perfectly fair and predictable systems are subject to gaming.

Comment: @jackwise You aren't exactly left with no questions to improve; you can _undelete_ the old ones.

Comment: @Xan I will try to do this, if I can ever get access to them. As far as I know, I can only undelete a question if I have a link to it.

Comment: If someone's getting their one question in six months, it'd be nice if the Stack Overflow UI said "This is your special opportunity. Be very careful to ask a good question.".

Comment: @PeterDuniho well this is off topic but are you available to help in c# closing and deleting on ocassion? In the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat room if so. I noticed a bunch of delete votes on c# closed questions that would be roomba'd anyway for sure and did not require delete votes. On a related note, we have lists of closed questions that ought to be deleted (imo), but are not getting roomba'd due to the roomba rules.

Comment: @Drew: _"but are you available to help"_ -- sorry, not these days. I already put as much time into SO as I can afford, and sometimes a bit more. I'm not sure how your room is different from the SOCVR room; I'm sure it's worthwhile, as the cleanup scripts are far from able to do the job perfectly, but I don't have time for either. (And yes, I'm probably one of those that cast delete votes for posts that would be cleaned up anyway, but I can never remember the specifics of what gets automatically cleaned up and it's too much trouble to try to review the list every time I want to vote "delete").

Comment: @PeterDuniho thx. I hear ya. I have roomba typed in the url making history suggestions so it is right there for me. And questions with no answers and a few downvotes are goners. Be well.