# Was I banned again because a user that upvoted my question was removed?

Tags: support, post-ban

I had a question ban 6 months ago. I waited patiently, and I got unbanned 2 weeks ago. Carefully I asked one question the other day, which got 1 upvote. Not overwhelming, but it was positive, that should be a start.

At one point, I noticed that I had lost 10 reputation, and when I looked, it said "A user has been removed". I simply thought, "crap, that sucks, I liked those points".

But now my question ban has been re-applied again.

Is there anything I can do here? I'd rather not wait 6 months for another try. :p

EDIT:

Thank you all of you who gave me a second chance by upvoting those questions you felt could be upvoted. The question ban has been lifted, I shall use this power responsibly.
So my guesses are that, it's either because of the -10 reputation drop, or that asking a single +1 upvoted question was still not enough to lift the question ban.

Comment: someone correct me if i'm wrong but a question ban doesn't have a set timeout. it's removed only when your questions improve, as per the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/1028804) *"The only way for the ban to be lifted is for you to start contributing positively to the site."* so it might be longer or shorter than 6 months

Comment: "Does the ban last forever?

If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated"

Comment: The 10 rep you lost is a question upvote. Basically, your new Q got you one upvote but you lost one with that removed user. Net effect: you are back where you started

Comment: Right, but that sounds stupidly draconic, it's not that I asked a bad question, someone somwhere on the site got banned and they took their reputation with them. I have no control over that, I honestly don't think it is fair to get banned again because someone else messed up

Comment: Is there a way to contact the mods?

Comment: @Patrice actually, the 10 rep loss is probably either *two* question upvotes or one *answer* upvote.

Comment: I wish this was documented, as I commented in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335628/do-duplicate-questions-count-towards-a-ban#comment401854_335628 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347709/question-ban-without-any-reason-after-long-awaited-ban-lift#comment464537_347709

Comment: Did you get banned 6 months for just [one single question with negative votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6202327/makogan?tab=questions&sort=votes)? That's harsh! (oh, or some questions may have been deleted, this I can't tell without being an elected moderator)

Comment: apparently :p I think the algorithm simply measures positive to negative upvote ratio over time over questions, so if you have 1 really negative question that puts you into a negative score and then a bunch of 0 questions, it considers that your average quesiton ratio is negative, so it pulls you down

Comment: How rude do you have to ask to get banned at all? oO

Comment: @Coeur i was checking the same profile ytd and there were indeed more downvoted Qs in there

Comment: You should get unbanned for life for waiting patiently.. 6 months is a minute. I’d create a new account on day 2. Jk. Good luck to you.

Comment: @PeterHaddad The community has spoken through it's votes and I am out of the ban!

Comment: Great, good job!

Comment: @Makogan Merry Xmas!

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaaaat? I did not know that StackOverflow can BAN users! I am surprised never knew this at all?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Glad the meta effect worked out for you. Sometimes users post here complaining about getting banned, except their question histories speak for themselves, and their often toxic attitudes don't help their cases either. In those cases, the meta effect ends up working *overwhelmingly against* their favor.

I think I speak for a lot of people when I say that your most recent question *is* considerably well-written though, as it ticks all the boxes that make a good question. (Disclaimer: I was totally one of those who upvoted it, and I did so prior to answering here.) And of course, your constructive outlook helps.

Keep up the good work.

---

You were blocked six months ago. This block allows you to ask one new question every six months, so in the six months that have passed, you've been allowed one question. This is the question you just asked. If you are still blocked, that just means [you were blocked the entire time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325880/why-hasnt-the-question-ban-on-my-account-lifted-after-six-months/325881#325881), and that question may very well not have been enough to put you out of the red. The removal of the user who voted for you in such a way as to generate 10 reputation (that you've now lost) may or may not have made any meaningful difference to your asking status.

There's not much you can do here, I'm afraid. Even we don't know how much more it will take to put you out of the red and get you asking questions regularly again. We can't disclose any information about the user that was deleted, not only by policy, but because our tools withhold it on purpose (except in cases of flagrant abuse). All I can tell you is to revisit your questions from time to time, and never be discouraged from making your next question the best it can be (after all, you only get one shot at this every six months, so you're going to want to make it count). Every question upvote helps.

> Well, I did try to improve my questions to the best that I could, but many of the questions that I got very downvoted on were related to me trying to use C in extraneaous ways because we were building an operating system and I was out of documentation. And a mixture of not knowing enough low level, and there being no documentation on baremetal on the PI3 led to subpar questions. And you may edit a question, but if people consider that the nature of the question itself is sub otimal, then you're kinda screwed either way.

I understand. It is an awful situation for well-meaning askers to be in, especially considering that post bans were intended to discourage those who *don't* want to improve. It feels to me that people downvote too often for the wrong reasons and not nearly enough for the right ones (if there's no documentation on something, you really shouldn't be downvoting a question that clearly says so, because that's absolutely not the fault of the asker at all — and by them asking, they're actually trying to help *create* it, albeit unofficially).

Comment: Well, I did try to improve my questions to the best that I could, but many of the questions that I got very downvoted on were related to me trying to use C in extraneaous ways because we were building an operating system and I was out of documentation. And a mixture of not knowing enough low level, and there being no documentation on baremetal on the PI3 led to subpar questions. And you may edit a question, but if people consider that the nature of the question itself is sub otimal, then you're kinda screwed either way.

Comment: This six-month limit is totally outrageous. If you have one downvote on your question for some reason - even if not a valid reason - the downvote trolls will take over and add a few more. Unfortunately, there are some mods who look only at the number of downvotes.

Comment: six months feel excessive... especially when technology moves so fast these days. a one month ban is probably long enough for people to think over.

Comment: @BoltClock: even worse, people rarely come back to revise their votes. Since they never get notifications when a post they voted on has been edited, that’s understandable. I have cast over 3000 votes. When should I check all of them, whether the post has been edited and the vote is still appropriate?

Comment: @Totoro 'the downvote trolls will take over and add a few more' this again.  Please either provide evidence of 'downvote trolls' or stop being abusive towards user-moderators.  This kind of insult is getting very annoying now, and I'm tempted to flag it:(

Comment: @Totoro that's a somewhat frequent claim. What is ALWAYS missing from these claims, is proof. When requested, users either don't provide anything, or provide a question that is indeed downvote-worthy

Comment: @A.Lau can we make a feature-request regarding that?

Comment: @john smith that question gets asked once every month. Check around, im sure youll find one.

Comment: @TinyGiant since the feature hasn't been made, we should ask again :)

Comment: @John smith that would be a duplicate, and a waste of time for everyone involved.

Comment: Mr. trigger-happy-at-Xmas @MartinJames, what makes you think that by "downvote trolls" he meant moderators of any kind, when he didn't? All he referred to is the well-known sociopsychological phenomenon "diffusion of responsibility", fueled by anonymity (and huge group size). It's a very natural and ubiquitous effect, and getting offended by its existence can only make things worse. (Now, if you meant the other part of his comment, then refine yours to be clear.)

Comment: Thanks @Sz, as you said I did not use that word to refer to moderators. An added problem is (with anonymity I cannot give any proof to this, but I know that it happens) there are some who are eligible to get a medal for their downvote, and they would most likely pounce on a newly-downvoted question.

Comment: 'I cannot give any proof to this, but I know that it happens': the cries of mob justice throughout the ages.  I accept that it's possible that 'there are those who are eligible to get a medal for their downvote would most likely pounce on a newly-downvoted question', and so my next question would be 'how big a problem is that?  Are there so many user-moderators so close to some badge and so inclined to downvote 'irregularly' that they make a noticeable difference to voting trends?

Comment: @Sz. On SO, downvoters, upvoters etc. are all moderators.  That's how SO works.  I admit to being unclear in my earlier comment: by 'user moderators' I meant 'regular users who provide moderation on SO by flagging/upvotes/downvoted/delete etc, not SO 'diamond' mods.

Comment: I mean, are there any badges you can get for just downvoting a question?

Comment: @Martin James: Critic ;)

Comment: @BoltClock OK, yes, and that badge is awarded once only.  Seems a little unlikely that there is a dynamic, cycling set of 'downvote-trolls' who are so desperate for the 'Critic' badge that they pick out a downvoted newbie question to add another downvote to without reading it and assessing it as 'bad' themselves.   I guess it's possible...or there could just be a Christmas-stockingfull of bad questions.  I'll go with Occam:)

Comment: RE "six months feel excessive... especially when technology moves so fast these days." Those are two extraordinarily unrelated matters. People that can't shape their problem into a meaningful question, will not be able to shape it properly in one month because Yet Another JavaScript Packaging Engine™ was created... Six months actually feels just right, and is possibly the *smallest* amount of time necessary for someone to change themselves in a meaningful way.